# How can proxy scrapy requests with Socks5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

**Question:**

How can proxy [`scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/) requests with `socks5`?

> I know I can use [`polipo`](https://www.irif.fr/~jch/software/polipo/) to [convert `Socks` Proxy To `Http` Proxy](https://www.codevoila.com/post/16/convert-socks-proxy-to-http-proxy-using-polipo)

**But:**

I want to set a Middleware or some changes in `scrapy.Request`

```py
import scrapy

class BaseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    """a base class that implements major functionality for crawling application"""
    start_urls = ('https://google.com')

    def start_requests(self):

        proxies = {
            'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080',
            'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080'
        }

        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                callback=self.parse,
                meta={'proxy': proxies} # proxy should be string not dict
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        # do ...
        pass
```

**what should I assign to `proxies` variable?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently **not possible**. There is [a feature request for it](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/747).

Answer (score 13):

It is possible.

#### HTTP Proxy to Socks5

Install [python-proxy](https://github.com/qwj/python-proxy)

```
$ pip3 install pproxy
```

Run

```
$ pproxy -l http://:8181 -r socks5://127.0.0.1:9150 -vv
```

#### Scrapy with HTTP Proxy

Create middleware (`middlewares.py`)

```
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = "http://127.0.0.1:8181"
```

Assign it to `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` (`settings.py`)

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'PROJECT_NAME_HERE.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 350
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest method I found as an alternative to `privoxy`. For a change got it working on 1st attempt !

Answer (score 2):

The middleware could be like:-

```
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.meta['proxy'] = "socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"
```

Make it available in your settings.py file and see if it works.

Comment: Did u mention in the settings.py and attached the priority?

Comment: Yes, this is a request feature in scrapy. https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/747

Comment: I see. Could u use http proxy instead? or is it a necessary requirement to use socks proxy only?

Comment: I've already used ``polip`` and convert socks proxies to ``http`` proxies, but actually it isn't a really good idea to solve this problem. and yes I have to use socks over ``http``

Comment: Well in that case i would suggest to opt for nodejs for scraping purpose. It provides you socks proxy support. Quite a few rich libraries for scraping like axios, puppeteer and they are easy to implement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know this is not really good practice but I've already mixed two frameworks and use`Django` beside `Scrapy`. I have to separate them and use another language for crawling.

Comment: Nope, this does not work. Scrapy does not support socks protocol, yet. Instead try using @almog approach, it works. Although you'd have an extra http bridge to reach socket

Answer (score 2):

Check it out, if it helps https://github.com/gregoriomomm/docker-multsocks...

It provides a way (as multiplatform as Docker is) to connect to a HTTP PROXY standard protocol to get to a SOCKS5 server with advanced route configuration, which is not readly provided by all softwares for free, like in Windows, which you can configure a simples HTTP proxy locally (see configuration at bottom).

It can also be use in this case, for many applications, like some old java implementations that can connect to SOCKS but are not enabled to correctly pass the user and password to authenticate SOCKS connection, so it can act as a SOCKS without authentication chaining to an authenticated.

It is based on common linux commands and can be also reproduced in Windows 10, by using the same commands on a shell with Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL).

In Ubuntu you can just install it

```
sudo apt install tsocks nmap

# Once you have a tsocks installed and configured 
echo "Starting http proxy!!!"
tsocks ncat -l --proxy-type http localhost 3128 &
```

Example of the /etc/tsocks.conf file (replace the variables with "v" ):

```
local = 9.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
local = 129.39.186.192/255.255.255.192

path {
reaches = 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
reaches = 158.98.181.232/255.255.255.248
reaches = 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0
server = vSOCKS_HOST
server_port = vSOCKS_PORT
server_type = 5
default_user = vSOCKS_USERNAME
default_pass = vSOCKS_PASSWORD
fallback = yes
}
```

If you want to try the docker version, just change the path/tsocks.conf
to your version it will load a HTTP SOCKS and SOCKS5 unauthenticated route to you SOCKS5 final destination server (and there are other options)

```
docker run -v path/tsocks.conf:/etc/tsocks.conf -p 3128:3128 -p 1080:1080  gregoriomomm/multsocks:latest
```

In https://github.com/gregoriomomm/tsocks have a version of tsocks (http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/) to enabled tsocks  (Transparent SOCKS5 proxing library) with minor adjustment to work and compile with Alpine:3.11 and included the same fallback option from Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi Gregorio, can you provide some more details behind your github project in the answer? Github may not be around forever and having the answer on this page would be helpful. If there's too much code, maybe a summary of steps that would help people trying to do the same thing?

Comment: It provides a way (as multiplatform as Docker is) to connect to a HTTP PROXY standard protocol to get to a SOCKS5 server with advanced route configuration, which is not readly provided by all softwares for free, like in Windows, which you can configure a simples HTTP proxy locally (see configuration at bottom).

It can also be use in this case, for many applications, like some java implementations that can connect to SOCKS but are not enabled to correctly pass the user and password to authenticate SOCKS connection, so it can act as a SOCKS without authentication chaining to an authenticated.