# pproxy 2.7.8 Unable to tunnel http over ssl: You must specify --ssl to listen in ssl mode

Tags: python, ssl, https, http-proxy

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/qwj/python-proxy#protocols) I should write the command: `pproxy -l http+ssl://:8181 -r socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 -vv` in order to use the tor network with scrapy as [Almog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60723943/10314460) did, and it works for http protocol.

When I write `pproxy -l http+ssl://:8181 -r socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 -vv` it displays this error `You must specify --ssl to listen in ssl mode`. 
The documentation precise `--ssl SSLFILE` but I have no idea what's exactly is this file, I don't find anything with search engines. What is it ?

Answer (score 0):

The `--ssl` argument requires you to pass it an SSL cert and its corresponding keyfile - also shortly described in its help text.

```
pproxy --help
# ... etc ...
  --ssl SSLFILE     certfile[,keyfile] if server listen in ssl mode
```

If you want to create a test cert, you can create a self-signed certificate locally and use it.

```
mkdir pproxy_test
cd pproxy_test

# One-line command to generate a self-signed cert, valid for 365 days
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout server.key -out server.crt -days 365 -subj "/CN=example.com"

# now run proxy and pass it the cert and key we just made
pproxy -l http+ssl://:8181 -r socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 -vv --ssl server.crt,server.key
```

And your SSL proxy should start:

```
pproxy -l http+ssl://:8181 -r socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 -vv --ssl server.crt,server.key
Serving on :8181 by http(SSL)
DIRECT: 0 (0.0K/s,0.0K/s)   PROXY: 0 (0.0K/s,0.0K/s)
```

---

Here's a full setup to demonstrate...

1. Run the `socks5` proxy in one terminal

   ```
   pproxy -l socks5://:9050 -vv
   ```
2. Run the ssl proxy in a second terminal

   ```
   pproxy -l http+ssl://:8181 -r socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 -vv \
          --ssl server.crt,server.key -a 10
   ```
3. Demonstration: `curl` via the SSL proxy

   ```
   curl -k --proxy-insecure https://localhost:8181 example.com

   # this fetched me the example.com front page
   ```
4. Demonstration: `curl` via the SOCKS5 proxy

   ```
   curl -x socks5://localhost:9050 example.com   

   # also fetched me the example.com front page
   ```

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong. I wrote `openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout server.key -out server.crt -subj "/CN=whatismyipaddress.com"` then `pproxy -l http+ssl://:8181 -r socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 -vv --ssl server.crt,server.key`. I obtain the same displays as you show. But using it with scrapy by the book returns this: `2022-06-23 00:03:56 [SSL: HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST] https proxy request (_ssl.c:1129) from 127.0.0.1`,`2022-06-23 00:03:56 Unsupported protocol from 127.0.0.1`. so my webcrawler is stuck due to this.

Comment: @AvyWam I don't use or have familiarity with `scrapy`, but that error from py-proxy sounds like `scrapy` is not connecting to it or completing the SSL handshake. Does `scrapy` allow connecting to a self-signed SSL server by default?

Comment: I don't think this is due to scrapy itself. I used `127.0.0.1:8181` in my Firefox browser, with the customed parameters (and I know to do it because with socks5 it works well). It gives the same error: `2022-06-23 00:58:51 [SSL: HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST] https proxy request (_ssl.c:1129) from 127.0.0.1`,`2022-06-23 00:58:51 Unsupported protocol from 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @AvyWam It seems like your setup is incomplete, then. Did you also run the `socks5` proxy on port 9050? I included an example of my set up and I can proxy my requests through either the ssl proxy or the socks5 directly without issue.